# How to align list bullet image with li text

Tags: html, css, list

I am using image as bullet for list.

[image: list bullet and li text]

I am trying to align list item text to list bullet image, so that text will look like this:
[image: desired list bullet and text position]

How do I do I change list style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use background for insert image: http://jsfiddle.net/serGlazkov/cYAzV/162/

```
ul{ 
    list-style-type:none;
}
ul li{
    background: url("http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/smiley.gif") 0 50% no-repeat;
    padding-left: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
```